# Spotfire, Bar width option is greyed out

Tags: spotfire

[image]

I want to make my combination bar charts' width to be thicker, but it is greyed out as you can see. One pattern I observed is that if my Axis mode is continuous,  I the x-axis will show tick marks in 5 year interval, which is what I want, but it greyes out the bar width adjustment option.

How can I adjust my bar width while retaining my 5 year interval tick marks on my x-axis?

Comment: Is your category axis a continuous scale? i.e. does your catagory azis custom expression have a <> around it?